# Static table view - disclosure indicator to call phone number

Tags: ios5, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have a table view set to as static.  it has 4 cells in it. the first two cells are mapped to another view so that works fine,

I would like the other 2 cells to either call a phone number or launch email. I do have the code for both of these functions already.  I just dont know who to map the action of a cell selection to a function in the code.  when I right click on the cell, I only see push action for segue but I want to control this in the code.

Comment: Show your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` then I'll show you how to connect these other 2 actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the storyboard file and click on the the Assistant Editor button in the top right of Xcode.
It should open up the header file to the view controller associated with the view.  Now Ctrl and drag the cell you want to hook your code up to and drag it to the header file.  This will create an IBAction for you.  Now that it is hooked up, you can then call your method your created to handle the call or email.